# Rails Yaml Config (Best Practice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

Is it still considered a best practice to load some configuration parameters inside environment.rb with yaml files within the /config directory? It seems like a pretty good way to do this, but if there was a better way, it'd be good to know about it. I've tried to find articles about loading configuration settings in Rails / YAML but most of the articles don't go past 2009. Makes me feel like there came a better (or new standard) way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything you find lacking from using YAML?

Comment: nothing lacking about yaml at all. i like it. just get curious when i see so many articles on a solution that are dated. makes me wonder what i'm missing out on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using this gem for that purpose recently:

- SettingsLogic: https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

Basically, you create a `/config/application.yml` file that looks something like this:

```
defaults: &defaults
  api:
    johns_api_co:
      api_key: my_key
      secret: shh!!!

    other_setting:
      this: "is a config setting"
      that: "and another thing"

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

There are so many ways to do this, but this works well and is pretty straightforward.

Comment: looks interesting, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Heroku recommends storing config in your system environment vars (.env file on your local box) and use it with foreman gem. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

One advantage is that it hides all your credentials from your code repo, which is great when you want to make it publicly available.